# fscanf not working as expected.

Tags: c

I have a word file with 3 words. I need to read each word into an array. I tried doing this with `fscanf()`, but it doesn't work. What am I doing incorrectly?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
    char words_array[80];
    FILE *dictionary;
    dictionary = fopen("dictionary.txt", "r");
    fscanf (dictionary, "%s", words_array);
    printf("The content of words_array is: %s, %s, %s, \n", words_array[0], words_array[1], words_array[2]);
}
```

I get the following error when I try to compile:

> warning: format '%s' expects argument of type '* char' but argument has type 'int'

The `dictionary.txt` file is as follows:

```
apple
orange
bananna
```

Thanks all!

Comment: Is the warning about `fscanf` or `printf`? Your usage of `printf` doesn't make any sense. And I'm not sure what you're expecting `fscanf` to do, but I think you should read its manual.

Comment: Read the whole file into a single char * (string).  strtok() that string into separate arrays looking for new lines.  Or look into fgets() - this might do what you want if you make your word_array 2-dimensional.

Comment: Why accept an answer that does not conform to your criteria? `I need to read each word into an array.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have only one word (fruit) in one line (and < 80 characters long) in the `dictionary.txt`, the following should work!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char words_array[80];
    FILE *dictionary;
    dictionary = fopen("dictionary.txt", "r");
    while (fscanf (dictionary, "%s", words_array) == 1) {
        printf("%s \n", words_array);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ gcc fsca.c 
$ ./a.out 
apple 
orange 
bananna 
$ cat fsca.c
```

---

Adding an alternative answer as per request from the OP author.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char word1[80], word2[80], word3[80];
    FILE *dictionary;
    dictionary = fopen("dictionary.txt", "r");
    fscanf(dictionary, "%s", word1);
    fscanf(dictionary, "%s", word2);
    fscanf(dictionary, "%s", word3);
    printf("%s %s %s\n", word1, word2, word3);

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
$ gcc fsca.c 
$ ./a.out 
apple orange bananna
$
```

Comment: What I want to do is read each word into a different string in the array. Any idea how I might go about doing this?

Comment: @Number7even Yes it is possible, please check my answer. I have updated it with the new answer. Hope it helps! .. thanks! ;)

Comment: @Number7even If you find my answer satisfying, please feel free to click the tick mark next to it to confirm the same. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `words_array` has space for 80 characters. You're mistakenly thinking you have 80 words.  The printf line to print the first word is:

```
printf("The content of words_array is: %s\n", words_array);
```

If you want to print all the lines/words, you'll need to wrap this in a reader of the lines of the file:

```
while (fscanf (dictionary, "%s", words_array)) {
        printf("%s \n", words_array);
    }
```

read the man page for fscanf to see why.

[edit]

instead of the while  loop:

```
char words_array[3][80];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   fscanf(dictionary, "%s", words_array[i]);
```

[/edit]

Comment: What I want to do is read each word into a different string in the array. Any idea how I might go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

char words_array[80] is merely a character array - NOT an array of strings.

So when you try to print out words_array[0] and so on, they are characters and hence a mismatch with %s.

Also you would want to use feof for reading till the end of file. Just use fscanf till end of file is reached, read a string and print it out.

Comment: What I want to do is read each word into a different string in the array. Any idea how I might go about doing this?

Comment: You could use an array of character arrays for that. Essentially it then becomes an array of strings.

Comment: Like this: char some_array[80][80]

Comment: Yes, that is an array of 80 character arrays - each having 80 characters. Just refer to any standard documentation for examples on how to use it.